# Show that $\pi_1 ( \mathbb{R}^2 - \mathbb{Q}^2)$ is uncountable

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

This is question 1.2.17 from Hatcher, Algebraic Topology:

> Show that $\pi_1 ( \mathbb{R}^2 - \mathbb{Q}^2)$ is uncountable

My line of thinking is trying to show that there exists an injection 
$$
\begin{align}
\rho :\mathbb{R} \setminus \{ 0 \} & \to \pi_1 (\mathbb{R}^2 - \mathbb{Q}^2, (\sqrt{2}, 0) )\\
r & \mapsto [I_r]
\end{align}
$$
where $I_r$ is the square loop that goes around the corners
$$ (\sqrt{2}, 0) \to (\sqrt{2}, r) \to (-\sqrt{2}, r) \to (-\sqrt{2}, 0) \to (\sqrt{2}, 0) $$

Essentially, I'm trying to prove that if $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a \neq b$ then $[I_a] \neq [I_b]$. My intuition is that no point in $I_a$ is path connected to any point in $I_b$ so there's not going to be a homotopy between them; I'm unsure if this is enough and am looking for a rigourous way of expressing this.

Also, if anyone knows a nice, quick way of doing this question along a different line of reasoning, that would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your idea is fine. However, for rational $r$, your loop would pass through $(0,r)\in\Bbb Q^2$. You can mend this by taking only irrational $r$ (these are also uncountably many).

To see that really $[I_a]\ne [I_b]$ for $a\ne b$, note that there exists a rational $q$ between $a$ and $b$ and that exactly one of the two loops is contractible in $\Bbb R^2\setminus\{0,q\}$. This says that the images of $[I_a]$ and $[I_b]$ under the canonical map $\pi_1(\Bbb R^2-\Bbb Q^2,(\sqrt 2,0))\to \pi_1(\Bbb R^2-\{(0,q)\},(\sqrt 2,0))$ differ.

---

**Remark:** Can you see why $\pi_1(\Bbb R^2-A)$ is also uncountable where $A=\{\,(\tfrac1n,0)\mid n\in\Bbb N\,\}$? One needs a slightly different argument (or maybe the same argument, but with more elaborate loops)

Comment: Ah of course, I think I was imagining the irrationals in my head anyway but thank you for pointing it out! Is it true in general that if $A \subset X$ and the images of two loops in $\pi_1 (A, x_0) \to \pi_1 (X, x_0)$, say $[f], [g]$, are different, then the loops are not homotopic in $A$?

Comment: Also with the remark, I feel like you could construct the loops using the same loops but coming from $\mathbb{R} \setminus A$ instead of $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$